# .htaccess to redirect images

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i'm still new to the redirectrule thing from htaccess and have successfully redirected my pages so that the pretty URL shows up, but is there a way to redirect the images so that it is not relative? Is there a way or function that allows me to redirect images without changing it one by one ?

Like i after redirecting the page, i get relative URL, hence my images are showing something extra in their links.

so this is the actual url to the image

```
http://www.yousite.com/page/images/this.jpg
```

but i'm getting stuff like

```
http://www.yoursite.com/images/page/images/this.jpg
```

Comment: Can you give examples of what your URLs look like now versus what you'd like the redirects to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this will solve the problem, but instead of modifying all the links you could use the **BASE** element in each page to define a base URI:

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4:

> When present, the BASE element  must  appear  in the HEAD section of an
>   HTML document, before any element that refers to an external source. The
>   path information specified by the BASE element only affects URIs in  the
>   document where the element appears.

Examples:

```
 <HEAD>
   <BASE href="ImagesBasePath">
 </HEAD>
```

Or just:

```
 <HEAD>
   <BASE href="/">
 </HEAD>
```