# A strange .htaccess issue I think?

Tags: .htaccess, stylesheet

I have a web site where I'm using the basic wordpress .htaccess file to dump any request to the index. Everything works as expected when I type in www.mydomain.com

It works as expected when I type in www.mydomain.com/something

But if I use any more slashes such as www.mydomain.com/something/ or www.mydomain.com/something/something the index page loads but some kind of error causes the stylesheet not load.

It's like the page loads but without styles. Does anyone have a clue why this is behaving this way?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446835/htaccess-to-redirect-images/15447517#15447517) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have relative paths for your stylesheets.  You can fix it by using absolute urls to force the requests for your stylesheets to come from a specific URL instead.