# Removal of .php for files in specific folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hosting

I have this site called precisely.me, and I have just bought a new hosting server for it.

In my .htaccess file, I want all my files within precisely.me/fpl/*.php to also be accessible via precisely.me/fpl/*. For eg -: precisely.me/fpl/epl-table.php should also be accessible via precisely.me/fpl/epl-table

Why is this not working?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I am using GoDaddy.com's hosting, and should admit that I have little knowledge about the .htaccess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this instead, in one .htaccess file in root directory.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.php      [NC]
RewriteRule ^fpl/([^/]+)/? /fpl/$1.php  [L,NC]
```

Maps silently:

`http://precisely.me/fpl/filename`

To:

`http://precisely.me/fpl/filename.php`

Where *filename* is a dynamic string.

For permanent redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC].

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. What's the difference in permanent redirection, and this?

Comment: Also within my php file, if at the end of a file I have header("Location: epl-table"), why do I get this - "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/77/... in /home/content/77...../fpl/epl-table-decider.php on line 118";

Comment: With *permanent* redirection the substitution URL is displayed in the browser's address bar. When the URL is just rewritten or mapped, the original URL in the address bar is the requested one. That's the main difference in this case.

Comment: That happens often in PHP. You have to make sure the script has no previous output, so basically the relevant code has to be at the top of the file. I usually use javascript for that reason.

Comment: I think you made an error. My css/js files stopped being loaded. The second I remove this code, my start starting working again.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the rules. The reason for that is you are using relative paths instead of absolute paths for the CSS and other relevant files. The way to corrected it is modifying the paths in the scripts that call those files or using the BASE element. Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446835/htaccess-to-redirect-images/15447517#15447517) for more info on how to do it