# Can't display images after using Apache RewiteEngine / .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a question here:

On my server, there is:

http://www.domain.com/folder1/abc/html/index.html

In index.html there are some links of images or pdf files:

Then I use .htaccess make the URL shorter and it works:

http://www.domain.com/~abc

But from browser, the link of the image shows:

http://www.domain.com/pic.jpg

which can not be displayed. And even I tried to visit:

http://www.domain.com/~abc/pic.jpg

I got a 404 Error.

Here is my .htaccess, Am I wrong with something or missing something?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^~(.*)$  /personalpages/personal_space/$1/html/
RewriteRule ^~(.*)$/(.*)$  /personalpages/personal_space/$1/html/$2
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: But always starts with `~`? It seems it is a relevant character in your rules.

Comment: abc could be any name. Acturally, what I'm going to do is to build personal homepages: create a folder named abc(could be user's name), upload files he provied and make URL shorter for good remember.

Comment: just like [link](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~aretakis/)  I think this is a common usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/personalpages/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$   /personalpages/personal_space/$1/html/  [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/personalpages/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)/?$  /personalpages/personal_space/$1/html/$2  [L,NC]
```

Comment: hi @faa, thanks for your help. There is something unclear in my post. I edited .htaccess part.

Comment: Yes. It looked different, that's why I edited your post. Check it.

Comment: And please refresh the page, I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: I am confused about why the image link on the page is www.domain.com/pic.jpg, it should be www.domain.com/~abc/pic.jpg Right? If so, then we can adjust htaccess settings to make pic.jpg displayed correctly.

Comment: The first thing is to modify the rules as in my answer, so they work as expected. Once you have them working, if the images, CSS and other scripts don't load is because you are using relative paths in their links. Have to use absolute paths or the BASE element. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446835/htaccess-to-redirect-images/15447517#15447517) for more info on how to use the last one.

Comment: Thank you very much @faa I need some time to try and understand your solution. Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: It works after I add <base href="/~abc/" /> in the HEAD. Thank you so much.