# Rename Url .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with mod-rewrite to rewrite these url:

```
mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/file
mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/file&id=10
```

into these

```
mywebsite.com/file
mywebsite.com/file/10
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: not hard to find this in a web search

Comment: Yes, i tried this: ^file/?$ /index.php?page=folder/file [NC,L]

Comment: Do you want to change `index.php?page=x` into `x` or the other way around? It's not clear.

Comment: The files aren't in the same folder,i  think that's why it's not working

Comment: @João Rafael Martins: you've used `^file/?$` in your attempt. What do you think it means?

Comment: I think it should display mysite.com/file/ instead of file.php, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/file`
>   `mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/file&id=10`
>   into these
>   `mywebsite.com/file`
>   `mywebsite.com/file/10`

It is not clear if *folder* is a fixed string or the directory where *file* is, so in this answer it is assumed to be a fixed string as the directory in both cases is root.

You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/?$  /index.php?page=folder/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /index.php?page=folder/$1&id=$2  [L,NC]
```

Maps silently:

`http://mywebsite.com/file` to
`http://mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/file`

And

`http://mywebsite.com/file/10` to
`http://mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/file&id=10`

Where strings **file** and **10** are assumed to be dynamic.

For permanent redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: Im using this, but not is happening, any idea why?

Comment: Try using [R,L,NC] instead of [L,NC] in both rules so you can **see** the redirected URLs.

Comment: Nothing changed, URL still http://mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/file, I don't know why. I used this "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]" just to remove index.php and it worked, do you know why the first one is not working?

Comment: Most probably the regex is not matching the request URL structure. It should be exactly as described in your question. Please copy+paste into one comment the complete testing URLs you are using.

Comment: http://testsite.co.cc/index.php?page=nav/home and http://testsite.co.cc/index.php?page=nav/news&id=74 where "nav/" is a directory

Comment: Well, now I know why it doesn't work. I am not sure if your idea is to have "pretty" URLs, but if that's the case you have it all backwards. The request should be `http://mywebsite.com/file`, which is displayed in the address bar all the time while it is silently redirected to the resource `http://mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/file`. However, if that's not the idea I can modify my answer to do the opposite, but you should be aware that if the substitution URLs in this case are in turn redirected back to the requests, there could be loops and performance will be affected.

Comment: Oh, know i understand, sorry. it's the first time i'm using mod-rewrite, i think now it will work, thank you.

Comment: its not necessary, i'm using this now: "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=folder/$1 [L]" the only thing is this now"RewriteRule ^file/(.*)/$ index.php?page=folder/file&id=$1 [L]" am i doing this right?

Comment: Which file/id it's specific like url.com/news/id

Comment: Did you try my answer? The first rule is used only when the request has 1 parameter (`/file`) while the 2nd one is used when it has 2 parameters (`/file/10`). It passes the parameters in the order described in your question. Using (.*) is not a good idea as that group contains the whole URI-path and there is no way to select the parameters to pass them in the correct order.

Comment: It's all working now, but it seems that the css is not loading

Comment: That has nothing to do with the rules, although it's a consequence of them as the requests are different. The way to correct it is using absolute paths in the CSS links, images, etc. Or, using the BASE element. Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446835/htaccess-to-redirect-images/15447517#15447517) for information on how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You want somthing similar to this

```
#With mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/file/(.+)  /index.php?page=folder/file&id=$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule   ^/file       /index.php?page=folder/file [R,L]
```

Comment: Do i Have to write "mywebsite.com"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to rewrite and NOT TO REDIRECT `mywebsite.com/$var` into `mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/$var` and `mywebsite.com/$var1/$var2` into `mywebsite.com/index.php?page=folder/$var1&id=$var2`? You can check this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?page=folder/$1

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?page=folder/$1&id=$2
```