# Manipulating displayed url in client-browser

Tags: php, url

Well, hello folks

I am looking for a way to manipulate the displayed url in the clients browser.

Example:

```
User is currently looking at /articles?id=25689
```

But in the browser url should be something like:

```
/articles/ItIsABeautifulDay
```

Is this possible using Php? Or do I need some clientside scripting?

Comment: Here is some similar question and it's answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777229/rename-url-htaccess

Comment: You should check out the `mod_rewite` module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you for the htaccess hint @levi.  Problem is: This application will run on client servers and I really don't want them to change their htaccess!

Comment: ohh i got it @NoelWidmer the only way that i know is using mod_rewite, but you will need change htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you both @Krister Andersson I will have a look at the mod-rewrite->Gonna take some time probably...Thank you!

Comment: Try http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to manipulate a URL like this.
You use the GET method so you'll always see your parameters in the URL.

There are several solutions for this.

- You can use the POST method, but some people say that this is slower
  than GET. It can be true but I think that the delay between Get and
  POST is not so big.
- You can handle you're code in a seperate file and redirect to an
  other webpage when the process of your code is done.

Maybe there are others solutions but this are the two I know. :)

Comment: I know it is possible using js! The soul pourpose of this is, that the application-admin can choose how his url-links look like. He will actually be able to change the look of the urls. No matter how he changes them no files or directories should be renamed! Only the displayed url name. If you are interessted you may want to check out wordpress. That's where this idea is from :)

Comment: Ok, I see, but are there some disadvantage by doing this? And why should you manipulating URL's?

Comment: Well, there are maaany advantages!

Comment: f.e. if a user sees a link like: /articles?id=5465132 then he has no idea what is looking at. But if I change it to /articles/holidays2013 he gets usefull info. Or I can change it to /AboutMe or /YourPaymentOptions. This is very usefull to give more info if someone is watching a link. Remember, there are users that will change links bevore they click it. Sometime they may change /2013/April to /2012/January just to see what I posted back then. It's really cool! All this is possible by faking the url.

Comment: And yea, there can be disadvantages of course. f.e. if the admin switches the display behavior after a bit of time. Because all the links that other pages may referr to won't work any longer. Anyway, I would fix this by adding a linkversion to the manipulated link. Everytime the admin changes the behavior I would change this...I easly can tell how the link should be processed :) Got it?

Comment: Yes, but I think there are a lot of people who don't look to the URL. Of course, it's always nicer when you have a short link without all the GET-stuff ;)

Comment: Your right! It's probably the nasty 1% that really do have a look at the url. But don't forget all the other websites or blogs that may referr to your page! When you see a link in a blog it's ALWAYS better to see what it is about.

Comment: Thx - Good luck with your array, that calculates some position of a ball. Well, I didn't quite get it...hehe :)