# Redirect all requests under a domain to an under construction folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have been trying to redirect all requests under a domain to an underconstruction folder with the following:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/underconstruction/
 RewriteRule ^ /underconstruction/ [R=301]
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I tried this (and it works):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/underconstruction/underconstruction.html
RewriteRule ^ /underconstruction/underconstruction.html [R=301]
```

But I don't see the images and CSS that it comes with it.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: The rule works but the page doesn't display correctly, is that it?

Comment: yes the page displays, but the css and images dont

Comment: link the css and images to the correct full path instead. (e.g., http://www.domain.com/images/1.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe one solution is to exclude all image and CSS files from the rule, like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
# Add or remove file types in the next line if necessary.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|png|gif|bmp|js)  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !underconstruction\.html  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   /underconstruction/underconstruction.html [R=302,L]
```

Other options are to replace relative with absolute paths in the links to those files or to use the BASE element as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446835/htaccess-to-redirect-images/15447517#15447517)

Comment: Don't forget the .js files

Comment: Yes. Good point. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sooo much!, this was 10 out of 10  helpful

Comment: Youre awesome man thanks