# Absolute links and temporary URL with /~username

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm moving a large site to a dedicated server.  At the moment I have to access it like so http://[dottedquad]/~username/index.php

This is making all of my absolute links break.

Is there a mod_rewrite recipe to say if a file is not found check that same path prefixed by /~username?

Or a global way to set a base href without having to update the files?

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446835/htaccess-to-redirect-images/15447517#15447517) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check if a file exists...

```
#whatever your original rewrite rule is
RewriteRule ^(.+) regular/place/$1 [NC,QSA]

#if file does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#use the other path
RewriteRule ^(.+) ~username/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

If the ReWriteCond found the file, the second rewrite rule won't ever fire.  If it did, the second rewrite rule will fire.

My regex is probably off, but hopefully you grasp what I'm talking about.  The key is the "!-f" which is basically supposed to check for the file.