# Rewrite Friendly php URL for multiple languages using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a couple websites that I built a CMS for that will save the languages in an XML file and depending on the page and language selector, it will show the correct data. I cuurently have 8 different languages for each of the sites and the urls are like:

http://leclosdamboise.com/index.php?lang=fr

http://leclosdamboise.com/rooms.php?lang=en

http://leclosdamboise.com/hotel.php?lang=de

I am trying to have it so that the urls are rewritten to look like this:

http://leclosdamboise.com/fr/index.php

http://leclosdamboise.com/en/rooms.php

http://leclosdamboise.com/de/hotel.php

I have spent hours combing through forums and not been able to find a solution that works. My .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_TEST
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This does not do anything and the urls are still the ugly step-daughter version. The links above are actual links to one of the sites. Once I sort this out I need to deply it to several sites, but been racking my head trying to sort this out. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php  /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Hmm, Ok, that seemed to work. But now all my relative links are messed up, as the page thinks that it is one level deeper. Is there a way around that, or am I just going to have to absolute path everything now? ...

Comment: Maybe the modification in my answer solves that issue. If it doesn't, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446835/htaccess-to-redirect-images/15447517#15447517) on how to use the BASE element. Might help.

Comment: Yes, by adding <BASE href"site.com/"> to my header all the relative links for images and such still work. Thank you. Now I just need to add a language detection for the index page and I'm all good.