# Redirect language query string to subdirectory for better SEO

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, multiple-languages

I'm developing a web site that supports multiple languages (english and spanish) in PHP using parameters like this:

```
www.website.com/contact?lang=en
www.website.com/contact?lang=es
```

Yes, without extension .php...
I know that is a bad practice, so I want to have this:

```
www.website.com/en/contact
www.website.com/es/contact
```

I read other posts here in stackoverflow but, I don't want to use a PHP framework, and I read that I have to use Mod Rewrite (again because I already use it for remove the extension). In fact, I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804980/rewrite-friendly-php-url-for-multiple-languages-using-htaccess-file) (and others too), but nothing works.

When it is done, I read in google pages that I have to use:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.website.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

is this correct?

Thanks

EDIT 1:

The content of my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteBase /

#Prevent directory listing
Options All -Indexes

#Disable Etags
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

#Prevent viewing of .htaccess
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine on

#Redirect non-www/www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
#Rewrite url
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)  /$2?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Why is `.php` removal bad practice? Do you want the pages every page to redirect if the lang parameter is added or just contact?

Comment: No, sorry (it's my english), what is a bad practice is this "www.website.com/contact?lang=es" for SEO I think...

Comment: Oh, okay, with the param. So for the redirect do you only want to redirect the contact form when it has the `lang` parameter or all pages with that parameter should redirect?

Comment: @w3d https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#2

Comment: Thanks for the link - yes, you're right.

Comment: @Ismaestro Its funny that google marks parameter option as "Not recommended" but there are using `?hl=lang` all over their applications...

Comment: @fat_mike here you have more information: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en , and additionally check this https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/2370587?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your full .htaccess with a new rule to redirect lang specific URLs:

```
#Disable Etags
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

#Prevent viewing of .htaccess
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Redirect non-www/www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect /contact?lang=en to /en/contact
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+([^?]+?)(?:\.php)?\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This, and change links to this format: <a href="/<?= $lang ?>/contact">Contact </a> Works fine! Like @w3d said

Answer (score 2):

even if you use the solution from the post you marked out with a tiny adaption to meet your missing php file endings:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)  /$2?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What is this suppose to be doing?

Comment: it is a .htaccess file for the mod_rewrite that will change urls of http://example.com/en/contact to http://example.com/contact?lang=en

Comment: Yes @chris85 is richt. What I want is to convert example.com/contact?lang=en to example.com/en/contact

Comment: @Ismaestro Are you suggesting that in-page links contain the query string?

Comment: @w3d I have this link for example: <a href="how-it-works">How it works</a> and this goes to www.website.com/how-it-works. But if I change the language click a button for english for example, the url change to www.website.com/how-it-works?lang=en. But as I said this is a bad practice for SEO, so I want to rewrite the URL to www.website.com/en/how-it-works Maybe It's a bad idea or I am misunderstanding something...

Comment: @Ismaestro And when you click the `?lang=en` link you presumably set a cookie or session variable (so that all the links without the `lang` parameter know what language to show)? Unfortunately this isn't a _quick fix_ in .htaccess. Yes, .htaccess is required (as in hexerei's answer). But the links in your page (in fact, _all_ the links) need to first be changed to include the language. ie. `/en/how-it-works`. The directives in .htaccess then rewrite this URL back into the "real" URL ie. `/how-it-works?lang=en` (as above).

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of the redirects. You'll need to modify your links as @w3d has stated.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(en|es)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /%1/contact? [R=301,L]
```

The `|` in the query string means 'or' if you want other languages you can add them in there or you could change it to the less safe `.*`.